# Why funtion not defined in another function under exec?

Tags: python, exec, local-variables, global

```
test_str = '''
def test():
    print("test")

def hello():
    print("hello")
    test()

hello()
'''
def main():
    exec(test_str, globals(), locals())

main()
```

Output:

```
hello
name 'test' is not defined
```

But if I change locals() to globals(), everything is ok! Why?

Comment: I ran the code you used, and did not get the error you did.  Could you please provide a minimal, reproducible example?

Comment: sorry, I missed some code, could you retry the code above?